# Word for "Acting like an animal"

Tags: single-word-requests

I am writing a psychology paper describing an ASD (Autistic) client that acts like a cat, often meowing, nuzzling against objects, and walking around on all fours.

I was curious if there is a better word for "acting like an animal" than **zoomorphism** or **zoomorphic behavior**.

There are several threads on this site asking for "an antonym of anthropomorphic" and most of the responses bring up zoomorphism and or bestiality. However, I am hoping for one that best describes *the action of*, rather than *the state or attribution of animal traits*. Or is zoomorphism the best that can be done as the current English language stands?

Comment: Since such actions are almost certain to be comic (a young child exploring life, or a comedian; any related terms would be inappropriate) or related to some disorder, terms will almost certainly be either psychology-domain or again inappropriate (bestial, monster, feral...).

Comment: There is always "animalistic", but it has pejorative connotations.

Comment: Word choice might depend on how age-appropriate this behaviour is. How old is the client?

Comment: 4-5years of age

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The disorder has been called [**Clinical lycanthropy**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clinical_lycanthropy).

As for the sentence, to make it sound less coarse you could write:

*The patient behaves in a manner that resembles animal behavior.*

or

*The patient acts in a catlike manner (or displays zoanthropic behavior.)*

Answer (score -1):

"beastly" seems unpretentious as well as apt.

Comment: The question is asking for a technical word for the action which could be used in a diagnosis. This is unsuited. You might explain **why** *beastly* fits as an answer to the question.

Answer (score -1):

feral would be an excellent word.

Comment: The question is asking for a technical word for the action which could be used in a diagnosis. This is unsuited. You might explain **why** *feral* fits as an answer to the question.